# Creating a method that prints while emptying the contents of a Stack

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Given the class: 'AStack'

```
Object subclass: #AStack
    instanceVariableNames: 'elements'
...
```

It contains an OrderedCollection Object that holds it's 'element objects'

```
initialize 
super initialize.
elements := OrderedCollection new
```

It's member classes push and pop, respectively:

```
push: anObject 
self elements addFirst: anObject 

pop
^self elements removeFirst
```

I am trying to write a print method that uses timesRepeat to print the contents of the stack as well as empty it simultaneously. It calls the child class print method for each 'element' (print ^self name) and outputs it on the screen using 'Transcript'.

```
print
self size timesRepeat: [Transcript show: self pop print]
```

On the other side I have a class called 'SomeRandomObject' who's print method is:

```
print
Transcript show:self getName; cr
```

Workspace code:

```
| o1 o2 stk |

o1 := SomeRandomObject new.
o1 name: 'object1'.

o2 := SomeRandomObject new.
o2 name: 'object2'.

stk := AStack new.
stk push: o1.
stk push: o2.

stk print "prints and emptys stack"
```

Upon running I get the error:

**Error: Instances of AStack are not indexable**

How can I fix my code so the print method shows o1 and o2 name while popping them off the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot tell you exactly before you give me a full (at least bigger) stack trace, but I expect, that you wont have a `#size` method defined in your class which should be something like this:

```
size
  ^ elements size
```

Answer (score 1):

You would get the *"Instances of AClass are not indexable“* error if you sent `at:`, `at:put:` or `size` to instances of a class that has no *indexed instance variables* or has not overridden these methods.

So if you send any of these messages to instances of `AStack` (which has no indexed instance variables), make sure `AStack` defines the ones you send.